# How do I hide a radbutton in the code behind?

Tags: webforms, telerik

I have the following code:

```
 <telerik:GridTemplateColumn AllowFiltering="false"
 HeaderText="TEMPLATE">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <telerik:RadButton ID="download1" runat="server" Width="16px" Height="16px" Text="Download" Visible="false">
             <Image ImageUrl="../Images/funds.png" />
         </telerik:RadButton>
     </ItemTemplate> </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

The radbutton is contained in a radgrid. How do I hide the button dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Check here: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-accessing-cells-and-rows.html, the *Accessing Controls in Template Column* section treats templated columns. You could do this in the ItemDataBound event handler, for example, so you have the data to make the decision.

Of course, another option is to use server code block in the Visible property that will return true or false with your custom logic.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using vb.net here the specific solution:

```
Private Sub YourGrid_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridItemEventArgs) Handles YourGrid.ItemDataBound
    If e.Item.ItemType <> GridItemType.Item AndAlso e.Item.ItemType <> GridItemType.AlternatingItem Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("download1"), RadButton).Visible = false
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code behind:

```
download1.Visible = false;
```